# nginx several apps on one domain https issue with dotnet core

Tags: nginx, centos7

I'm new to nginx. I want to apply the same scenario in IIS to the nginx. There is a site on IIS and there are 2 applications attached to it. I applied a method but I am not sure if it is a correct method.

I'm drawing the scenario directly;

```
Site -> www.example.com
     Application(Angular) -> www example.com/app
     Application(.Net Core API) -> www.example.com/api
```

[image: IIS Scenario]

I want to do the scenario mentioned above in nginx.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf ->

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        root   /home/www/example-web;
        index  index.html;
    }

    location /app {
        alias /home/www/example-app;
        index index.html;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
#        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

"wget http://www.example.com/api/values --no-check-certificate"

When I run the above code, I see it;

```
--2020-11-07 18:06:15--  http://www.example.com/api/values
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: https://localhost:5001/api/values [following]
--2020-11-07 18:06:15--  https://localhost:5001/api/values
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:5001... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify localhost's certificate, issued by ‘/CN=localhost’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-11-07 18:06:15 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Why redirects to https://localhost:5001/api/values?

should be redirected to the address below->

**http://localhost:5000/values**

How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: The redirect comes from your backend server, not nginx. Configure your backend server with the correct base URL.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it was mistake in dotnet service. I solved the problem with https but I couldn't solve the routing problem. Routing problem still persists. Redirecting to http://localhost:5000/api/values but I want redirect to http://localhost:5000/values. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the HTTPS problem by adding below code into the dotnet-my-api.service;

```
Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:5000
```

I solved the location problem by remove the path with an nginx proxy_pass;

```
location /api/ {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/;
        ...
}
```